# Toolchain: Shared Libraries instead of executable within usr/bin

Tags: linux, yocto, toolchain

I was given a toolchain by my vendor (the toolchain is from yocto project -- 5.10.52-hardknott). It was given in shell script file .sh file. When I execute it and install it in the location, I found that most of the executables(executable (application/x-executable)) is of type shared libraries (shared library (application/x-sharedlib)) shown in figure

[image: Example of what I see]

I tried to use file in terminal, for example file aarch64-poky-linux-ar

```
/opt/xxx/usr/bin$ file aarch64-poky-linux-ar
aarch64-poky-linux-ar: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1, BuildID[sha1]=78647fddeb218a15b0ccbcaae3ec2330d9a51d2f, for GNU/Linux 3.14.0, stripped
```

which indicates it is a library

I have thought it might be due to the file being not executable so I begin to try

```
sudo chmod +x aarch64-poky-linux-ar
```

But it doesnt help at all.

What have I done wrongly?

Thanks

Comment: In their documentaion, do they ask you to run `shared object` directly ?

Comment: @Philippe I do not have amy of their documentation except site-config file and manifest

Comment: @Philippe I think I know what you meant https://askubuntu.com/questions/690631/executables-vs-shared-objects#:~:text=A%20shared%20object%20file%20can%20be%20a%20library%2C,executable%20%28PIE%29%20using%20address%20space%20layout%20randomization%20%28ASLR%29.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66082164/open-compiled-c-program-from-file-manager

Answer (score -1):

This is most likely just `file` not categorising properly. Is there an actual problem or are you just confused by the binaries appearing as library instead of binary?

Comment: Is this an answer? It looks like a comment...

Comment: @ross burton just find it strange that shared libraries(presumed without main) could act as executable. Upon seeing the post above it seem plausible

Comment: There's no real difference between a shared library and an executable. You can run the ld.so, for example.